# How to make grails generate addTo* methods from both sides of many-to-many relationship

Tags: grails, many-to-many

I am trying to make a simple publication database via Grails 2.4.4 (standard ggts 3.6.3 bundle).
My domain classes look like this:

```
class Person {
  ...
  static hasMany = [publications: Publication]
  static belongsTo = [Publication]
}

class Publication {
  ...
  static hasMany = [authors : Person]
}
```

The problem is that when I try to prepopulate the database from some script in the BootStrap with the following code:

```
Publication publication = new Publication(...)
  .addToAuthors(somePerson)
  .save();
```

I get: `No signature of method: Publication.addToAuthors() is applicable for argument types: (Person) values: [Person : 1]`

Changing ownership in relation from Publication to Person does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce the issue but it seems working fine for me e.g:

```
class Person {
    String name
    static hasMany = [publications: Publication]
    static belongsTo = [Publication]
}
```

and

```
class Publication {
    Date pubYear
    static hasMany = [authors : Person]
}
```

and In Controller I created a Publication object and added two Person object to this Publication instance and every thing working fine as I can see the entries saved in DB.

```
  new Publication(pubYear: new Date()).addToAuthors(new Person(name: "Abdullah"))
                                      .addToAuthors(new Person(name: "Mohd"))
                                      .save(flush: true)
```

For further See [Doc](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#manyToMany)

Comment: Thanks, Abdullah, after I created a new test project with your code, it worked just as it meant to. My main project still generated the same error, but after some manipulations, it started to work properly. I can't understand which change did the trick because the final code is precisely the same as the one I started with. Perhaps the problem is with Eclipse caching or something like that.